# Silverlight or ASP.NET for slow and old clients

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, performance, ria

This is my scenario: Our big customer demands that we should develop a part of our ERP solution as a web application. He's bringing hundreds of new users who have pretty old computers on a small bandwidth. Since we have very small experience with building RIA web applications and we develop only in .NET framework I'm asking which technology have the greatest potential performance wise? Small bandwidth is our greatest concern, old computers (512Mb RAM or less, WinXP) are our second concern.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your current team expertise in .NET technologies? Does your team have experience delivering a Silverlight or ASP.net Web form or ASP.net MVC solution?

The minimum system requirement for Silverlight 4 requires at least 512-MB of RAM.

There is also some debate going on around the future of Silverlight as there are quite a few unanswered questions at this point of time.

In my opinion, Silverlight has a slightly longer learning curve compared to say ASP.net MVC.

I would recommend using ASP.net MVC with JQuery for the constrained environment that you want to support.

If you supporting streaming media etc is part of your requirement then you may want to check whether you can support a HTML5 complaint browser on your client machines running XP (Firefox 5 supports XP). You can integrate HTML5 support in ASP.net MVC.

You will obviously need to do some feasibility study for both technology solutions.

Comment: We have no expertise in Silverlight, ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC as a team. None. There will be no streaming of media also.

In our system architecture UI is only allowed to use our business classes which means that database is completly hidden from UI. Does this change your recomendation of MVC since Model is usually O/R mapping to database tables. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Since you have no experience with either technologies. I would recommend first working on an ASP.net MVC prototype. 

Silverlight will require comparatively more time to learn for e.g. understanding how to debug say data bindings etc will take some time. It is likely that with newer version of Silverlight the minimum System Requirement could change.

You can create a decent UI using JQuery in ASP.net MVC.

Comment: You don't always work directly with DB tables. For example - you may have a Web Service in between your App and DB. I believe what you said about O/R is more geared towards restriction of not directly working with DB from your app. 

You can write Mapper / Translators that can map from one entity to another similar to O/R mapper OR use appropriate ORM frameworks that will map from Web Service entities to your App Model. 

When working with views you can think about using View Models.

I recommend creating prototype using ASP.NET MVC3 and in the process a lot of your queries will be answered

Comment: Well, you've sold the idea to me. I'll make a demo app using MVC3 for evaluation. Thanks.

Comment: Glad, I could help. Please do post your findings from the feasibility study, if possible, and the technology choice you finally make. It might help someone else.

I work with both Silverlight and ASP.net MVC at the moment. And there are numerous criteria for choosing the technology that is just right for your project needs. To start with, try to aim for the technology to naturally blend in to your requirements instead of technology defining your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what skills you have. A web app would be best as the only client requirements are a web browser.

But it means building a web app, which if you're not familiar with developing, may slow you down. Silverlight will be closer to what you're familiar with.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has a numerous advantages over ASP.NET. But the old computers is very serious restriction to it. I suggest to develop some "prototype" of yours application using Silverlight and then decide if will it be suitable for such old machines (512Mb RAM or less).

For a example visit  http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/ and watch how much memory it consumes.

Otherwise ASP.NET will be the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try to come up with an old computer from somewhere.